# What is ErrorMessagePerFolderCountReceiveQuotaExceeded?

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365-restapi

I'm synchronizing Office 365 mail folders via the Office 365 REST API by doing a `GET` on `me/MailFolders/{folder_id}/messages`. For two different accounts, I've recently been getting **500** responses to these `GET`s with the error code **ErrorMessagePerFolderCountReceiveQuotaExceeded** and error message *"The number of received messages has exeeded the quota for the folder."* (Typo theirs, not mine.)

I can't find any documentation on this error. What does it mean? What should I do to fix this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a sync to an Exchange folder via the Outlook REST API, you pass it a sync token. In response, the API returns a new sync token and a set of changes. And the client is expected to send the new token back with their next sync request.

With most systems that support sync, using a stale sync token (i.e. one that has been sent to the server once) in a subsequent request will generally just succeed with no problems. And Exchange appears to work like that... for the first 999,999 times you do it. On the 1,000,000th time (and each time thereafter), you get **ErrorMessagePerFolderCountReceiveQuotaExceeded**. This is (I think) because Exchange keeps track of each token that it's given out and updates the token in its store each time it's used for sync. If a client uses a stale token, Exchange views it as a new client and adds that stale token as a new entry in its list of active tokens. That active token list can have at most 1,000,000 entries. **ErrorMessagePerFolderCountReceiveQuotaExceeded** is the cryptic error indicating that Exchange's active token list has overflowed.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't seem to find any documentation for it either.

From the error message, it seems it might be related to the "Maximum number of messages per mailbox folder" limit on Exchange Online. Do you know if the folder contains 1M+ messages?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange-online-limits.aspx#MailboxFolderLimits

---

I guess my other idea would be that you're getting too many messages in too short of a time period. Suggestion would be to use the endpoint `GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders('{folder_id}')/messages` with `$deltaToken` and `$skipToken` to skip previously synced messages.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#synchronize-messages